# Number of value representation bits in a integer, according to the standard?

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer, c++14, bit

Consider the following helper structs:

```
template <class T>
struct bit_count_1:
std::integral_constant<
    std::size_t,
    std::numeric_limits<typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type>::digits
> {};

template <class T>
struct bit_count_2:
std::integral_constant<
    std::size_t,
    std::numeric_limits<T>::digits + std::is_signed<T>::value
> {};

template <class T>
constexpr std::size_t compute_bit_count() {
    using type = typename std::make_unsigned<T>::type;
    constexpr type zero = 0;
    constexpr type one = 1;
    constexpr type max = ~zero;
    type current = max;
    std::size_t i = 0; 
    while (current) {
        current >>= one;
        ++i;
    }
    return i;
}

template <class T>
struct bit_count_3:
std::integral_constant<
    std::size_t,
    compute_bit_count<T>()
> {};
```

For every integral type `T` such that `std::is_integral<T>::value` is `true` except `bool` do I have the guarantee, by the standard, that:

- `bit_count_1`, `bit_count_2` and `bit_count_3` have the same value `N`
- `T x = 1; x <<= (N - 1)` is well defined
- `T x = ~static_cast<T>(0); x >>= (N - 1)` is well defined

I am currently working on a C++ proposal, so I need to be sure whether this is true according to the standard, or not, and for the moment it's a little unclear for me.

Comment: You might want to swap one of the tags on this question for [tag:language-lawyer] to help attract the appropriate audience.

Comment: ...and one more for the plain "C++" tag, which is followed much more than C++11 and C++14. I would drop either [tag:C++11] or [tag:standards], but I'll leave that to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course, you have (somewhat)!

**[basic.types] 3.9\4**

> The *value representation* of an object is the **set of bits** that hold
> the value of type T.

**[basic.fundamental] 3.9.1\3**

> The range of **non-negative values** of a *signed integer* type is a
> subrange of the corresponding *unsigned integer* type, and **the** value
> **representation of each corresponding signed/unsigned type shall be the
> same**.

**[basic.fundamental] 3.9.1\7**

> The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a
> pure binary numeration system.<sup>50</sup>
>
> <sup>50)</sup> A positional representation for integers that uses the
> binary digits 0 and 1, in which the values represented by successive
> bits are additive, begin with 1, and are multiplied by successive
> integral power of 2, **except perhaps for the bit with the highest
> position**. (Adapted from the *American National Dictionary for
> Information Processing Systems*.)

But it depends on what are non-sign bits:

**[numeric.limits.members] 18.3.2.4\9**

> For integer types, the number of **non-sign bits** in the representation.

If they implied, that the sign bit must be **only** in the so called [sign-and-magnitude representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Sign-and-magnitude_method), then you would have these expressions evaluated as `true`:

- `bit_count_2<T>{} > bit_count_1<T>{}`, and
- `bit_count_2<T>{} > bit_count_3<T>{}`,

for the signed integer type T represented in the two's or one's complement.

But because of **[intro.refs]** and the representations of types specified in **6.2.6.2\2** of the standard for the programming language **C**:

> For signed integer types, the bits of the object representation shall
> be divided into three groups: value bits, padding bits, and the sign
> bit...

, it looks like the sign bit is present in two's and one's complement representations too!